# Cannot figure out why I am getting the error "PFPush does not have a member named sendPushInBackground"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I copied this from the parse documentation and I keep getting the error "PFPush does not have a member named sendPushInBackground" on the last line. I am not sure why

```
        let pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
        pushQuery.whereKey("deviceType", equalTo: "ios")

        let push = PFPush()
        push.setQuery(pushQuery) // Set our Installation query
        push.setMessage("Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly.")
        push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Comment: “Parse SDK now depends on Bolts.framework” - did you “dragged” Bolts.framework also in your project?

Comment: Yeah it is in my project

Comment: Are you sure? Tell me, please, if you have this `#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` in your `...-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant if I just had the framework in my project. I added the import in the bridge file and it worked great! Thanks. If you add this as an answer to the question I can mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PARSE DOC: v1.2.21 — August 22, 2014

"Starting this release, you'll need to drag `Bolts.framework` (and ParseFacebookUtils.framework if your app interacts with the Facebook SDK) into your Xcode project folder target. Both are located in the Parse SDK download."

So, if you are using it in Swift... after you dragged the Bolt framework you must add this "#import", too

`#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>` in your `...-Bridging-Header.h`

Happy coding!